# EE 2.7/Channel Form/PHP Notices from Channel_form_lib.php

Tags: expressionengine, safecracker

Empty Channel Form on one of my channels throws the following notices/errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: field_type
Filename: channel_form/Channel_form_lib.php
Line Number: 2742

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: field_type
Filename: channel_form/Channel_form_lib.php
Line Number: 2809
```

This is all that is in the open form tag:

```
{exp:channel:form channel="video" return="tell_your_story/thanks" }
```

Changing to a different channel removes the error

Answer (score 1):

The cause was a checkbox field with a short name of 'sticky'.  I needed this field as a workaround to keeping sticky entries on top when sorting randomly.  Renamed it to 'stick_to_top' and errors went away.